# Using function with entries from two 3D arrays (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

So let's say I have two arrays (numpy arrays that is):

```
array1 = 
[[[1, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
[[0, 2, 4], [0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0]],
[[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 0]]]
```

and

```
array2 = 
[[[2, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 3], [1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 3]],
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]]]
```

I then make a function like:

```
def array_calc(x,y,z):
    x*y+z
```

What I would like to do now is have the x-values come from `array1` and y-values from `array2`, and z-values just a constant I choose (let's say `z = 0)`, and then do the calculation on each entry of the arrays, and ultimately end up with a new array, where the calculation has been done, and I get something like:

```
array_result = 
[[[2, 0, 0], [0, 24, 0], [9, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 12], [0, 16, 0], [0, 16, 0]],
[[0, 0, 2], [0, 6, 2], [3, 0, 0]]]
```

But, I'm not quite sure how that is done.

Comment: According to your requested output it seems that z = 0, am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's my bad... :) I'll change it :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your arrays are `numpy` arrays, it is as simple as:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
y = np.array([[4,1],[0,2]])
z = 1

result = x*y + z

# result = array([[5, 1], [1, 3]])
```

Comment: That looks like an easy solution. But can you manipulate single entries with that method? For example, in my case I actually have a function where I divide by x. And some entries in the x-array does have the value 0 - which is obviously not mathematically correct. However, the function is alright, and therefore, I actually just want that specific entry, in the case of an x-value being 0, to be zero. So it doesn't even have to run the function, just say: if x = 0, then result = 0.

So basically that is my question: If I do it like that, will it work on a single entry, or the whole array?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html#numpy.divide) integer division by 0 will yield 0 (in python 2.7 at least). Float division by zero will yield either `inf` or `nan` (if you divide zero by zero).

Answer (score 0):

Using simple `for` loops:

```
import numpy as np

def array_calc(x, y, z):
"""Returns x * y + z with x and y 3D Numpy arrays and z a number"""
    new_arr = x.copy()
    for i in np.arange(x.shape[0]):
        for k in np.arange(x.shape[1]):
            for j in np.arange(x.shape[2]):
                new_arr[i, k, j] = x[i, k, j] * y[i, k, j] + z

return new_arr
```

With:

```
array1 = np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
[[0, 2, 4], [0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0]],
[[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 0]]])

array2 = np.array([[[2, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0], [3, 0, 0]],
[[0, 0, 3], [1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 3]],
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]]])
```

Returns:

```
array([[[ 3,  1,  1],
    [ 1, 25,  1],
    [10,  1,  1]],

   [[ 1,  1, 13],
    [ 1, 17,  1],
    [ 1, 17,  1]],

   [[ 1,  1,  3],
    [ 1,  7,  3],
    [ 4,  1,  1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A way I can think of is to iterate through them and perform your calculations.
This can be done with 3 dimensional arrays too but I just found it easier to do it with 2 dimensional arrays. I am sure there are other ways to reduce the complexity further down because 3 for loops is not the best solution but it gets the work done.

The code is here:

```
array1 = [[[1, 0, 0], [0, 6, 0], [3, 0, 0]],[[0, 2, 4], [0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0]],[[0, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2], [3, 4, 0]]]
array2 = [[[2, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0], [3, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 3], [1, 4, 3], [2, 4, 3]], [[0, 0, 1], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]]]
z=0
array_1 = reduce(list.__add__, array1)
array_2 = reduce(list.__add__, array2)
array_3 = [[0,0,0] for _ in xrange(9)]
len_array=9
for i in range(len_array):
  for l in range(3):
    array_3[i][l] = array_1[i][l]*array_2[i][l]+z
print array_3
```